# Nested Generic Lambdas in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I'm driving myself crazy trying to understand Expressions in LINQ.  Any help is much appreciated (even telling me that I'm totally off base here).

Let's say I have three classes

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<PersonLocation> Locations { get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<PersonEducation> Educations { get; set:}
}

public class PersonLocation
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Floor { get; set;}
    public string Extension { get; set;}
}

public class PersonEducation
{
   public string SchoolName { get; set;}
   public string GraduationYear { get; set;}
}
```

I'm trying to create a method that takes in a string, such as Locations.Name or Locations.Floor, or Educations.SchoolName which will then create a dynamic linq query

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = GetAllPeople();
GetFilteredResults(people, "Location.Name", "San Francisco");
GetFilteredResults(people, "Location.Floor", "17");
GetFilteredResults(people, "Educations.SchoolName", "Northwestern");
```

This `GetFilteredResults(IEnumerable<Person> people, string ModelProperty, string Value)` method should create an expression that is roughly equivalent to `people.Where(p => p.Locations.Any(pl => pl.Name == Value);`

I have this working if ModelProperty is a string, i.e. people.Where(p => p.Name == Value) looks like this:

```
string[] modelPropertyParts = ModelProperty.Split('.');
var prop = typeof(Person).GetProperty(modelPropertyParts[0]);
var sourceParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "person");
var expression = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(sourceParam, modelPropertyParts[0]), Expression.Constant(option.Name));
var whereSelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(orExp, sourceParam);
return people.Where(whereSelector.Compile());
```

Here's what I have been playing around with for an IEnumerable type, but I just can't get the inner Any, which seems correct, hooked into the outer Where:

```
/*i.e. modelPropertyParts[0] = Locations & modelPropertyParts[1] = Name */
string[] modelPropertyParts = ModelProperty.Split('.');

var interiorProperty = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
var interiorParameter = Expression.Parameter(interiorProperty, "personlocation");
var interiorField = Expression.PropertyOrField(interiorParameter, modelPropertyParts[1]);
var interiorExpression = Expression.Equal(interiorField, Expression.Constant(Value));
var innerLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<PersonLocation, bool>>(interiorExpression, interiorParameter);

var outerParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "person");
var outerField = Expression.PropertyOrField(outerParameter, modelPropertyParts[0]);
var outerExpression = ??
var outerLambda == ??

return people.Where(outerLambda.Compile());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `System.Linq.Enumerable.Any` is a static extension method.

Your `outerExpression` must reference `System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, bool>)`:

```
var outerExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable), 
    "Any", 
    new Type[] { outerField.Type, innerLambda.Type }, 
    outerField, innerLambda);
```

Take a look at these links for more information:

- [MSDN `Expression.Call(Type, String, Type[], params Expression[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107.aspx)
- [Some helpful, similar examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/01/14/building-custom-linq-expressions-made-easy-with-dynamicqueryable_2e00_.aspx).

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  That basically worked, the only problem is the type you pass in is incorrect.  It should be interiorProperty instead of typeof(Person)

Comment: Oh yeah, I see now.  Feel free to correct the answer (community wiki)